# How to grab the nth occurence of a float on a line using regex?

Tags: python, regex

The text file I'm searching through looks like a lot of text blocks like this:

> MKC,2017-06-23 07:54,-94.5930,39.1230,79.00,73.90,84.41,220.00,4.00,0.00,29.68,1003.90,10.00,M,FEW,M,M,M,9500.00,M,M,M,M,KMKC 230754Z 22004KT 10SM FEW095 26/23 A2968 RMK AO2 SLP039 T02610233

(That's all one line)

I'm looking to grab the 2nd occurrence in the line that matches `r',\d\.\d{2},'`, which in this case would be `0.00`

I don't know how to specify that I want the nth occurrence of the pattern.

Extra: I've never seen the first value that matches the same pattern go over 9.99, meaning 10.00 and then it would no longer match the same pattern, but it would be nice if there was a way to take this into account.

Comment: You could have non-capturing groups for the N-1 occurrences, and then a capturing group for the Nth occurrence. It would be a bit verbose.

Comment: Could you elaborate or link to some relevant documentation? Do you mean just take group(2) from the search?

Comment: It depends on how structured your data is. What I would mean is let's say you're looking for a specific Nth value after a certain starting pattern, `re.findall` won't cut it. What you can then do is write (repetitively) `(?:\d+.\?d*)`, for example, to search for a float but not capture it, and then use `(\d+.\?d*)` for a float capturing group. It's verbose, but if you need enough precision, it may be the best way.

Another way would just be to pre-filter using `match.start()` and `match.end()` and then find the Nth element using a simple pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.findall`, capture your floats in a list and then index it as needed.

```
In [85]: import re

In [86]: line = '''MKC,2017-06-23 07:54,-94.5930,39.1230,79.00,73.90,84.41,220.00,4.00,0.00,29.6
    ...: 8,1003.90,10.00,M,FEW,M,M,M,9500.00,M,M,M,M,KMKC 230754Z 22004KT 10SM FEW095 26/23 A296
    ...: 8 RMK AO2 SLP039 T02610233'''

In [101]: matches = re.findall(r'(?<!\d|M)-?[\d]+\.[\d]+(?=,|$)', line, re.M)

In [102]: matches
Out[102]: 
['94.5930',
 '39.1230',
 '79.00',
 ...
 '10.00',
 '9500.00']
```

If needed, convert to floats using a `map`:

```
In [103]: list(map(float, matches))
Out[103]: 
[94.593,
 39.123,
 ...
 10.0,
 9500.0]
```

---

An update to include `M`s:

```
In [130]: re.findall(r'(?<!\d|M)(?:-?[\d]+\.[\d]+)|M(?=,|$)', line, re.M)
Out[130]: 
['-94.5930',
 '39.1230',
 '79.00',
 '73.90',
 '84.41',
 '220.00',
 '4.00',
 '0.00',
 '29.68',
 '1003.90',
 '10.00',
 'M',
 'M',
 'M',
 'M',
 '9500.00',
 'M',
 'M',
 'M',
 'M']
```

Comment: This answer is great except that if a particular piece of the data is missing, they enter an 'M' instead of the float, so sometimes it isn't the 8th float in the line. Is there any way you could account for the possible 'M's in place of the floats? Maybe a way to only grab the floats that have a single digit in front of the decimal?

Comment: @Mdomin45 Okay, fixed. I've added lookaheads and lookbehinds so all your cases are covered and no spurious matches are made. If it helps, do consider marking it accepted. Thank you :)

Comment: How would you alter the regex so that it includes the date and time? e.g. date: 2017-06-21 time: 10:30

Comment: @Mdomin45 If you wanted all these extensions, you should've specified so at the start. I have a couple of suggestions for you. 1) Either learn regex and try to get it extended yourself, or 2) Ask a new question. :)

Comment: Well I know that I can just add `|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{2}:\d{2}`, but I'm looking for a way that looks neat.

Comment: @Mdomin45 Exactly.`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` for the date, and the time follows a similar format :).... No... I don't think it gets neater than that.

Comment: @Mdomin45 Interactive regex testers like [Regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) can be very helpful when taking the first steps with Regular Expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). It returns a list which you can access like so:

```
result = re.findall(r',\d\.\d{2},', input)
result[n] # will return nth instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `re.findall(regex, string, flags)` function in python. That returns non-overlapping matches of the patter in string in a list of strings. You could then grab the second member of the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid capturing all and save some resources (noticeable only on particularly large strings) by dynamically building your pattern to skip several occurrences and then capture your pattern:

```
def get_nth_occurrence(pattern, data, n=0):  # n is zero indexed
    result = re.search("(?:{0}.*?){{{1}}}({0})".format(pattern, n), data)
    return result.group(1) if result else None
```

You can test it as:

```
test = "MKC,2017-06-23 07:54,-94.5930,39.1230,79.00,73.90,84.41,220.00,4.00,0.00,29.68," \
       "1003.90,10.00,M,FEW,M,M,M,9500.00,M,M,M,M,KMKC 230754Z 22004KT 10SM FEW095 26/23 " \
       "A2968 RMK AO2 SLP039 T02610233 "

print(get_nth_occurrence(r"\d+\.\d{2}", test, 1))  # 39.12
```

Of course, this has a limited use as you cannot really create complex patterns this way - for example, if you used a group in your pattern it will return that group instead.